# Subscribing events from Polkadot blockchain

Tags: polkadot, events

I would like to ask you how to subscribe events from Polkadot blockchain?
I am writing a rust application and I need this functionality there.

Is the using Substrate  the right direction to achieve that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

subxt has your back. Here's an example:

https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/master/examples/examples/subscribe_all_events.rs

(Events are just the `system.events` state at a certain block, so if you know the block hash you're after you can retrieve them by via a storage query)

(if you want to subscribe to blocks there's an example in the PRs)

Comment: Broken link at this point. I couldn't find a current example in the repo that seems to demonstrate how to subscribe to events.

Comment: I take that comment back, sorry. The example as of time of writing is here: https://github.com/paritytech/subxt/blob/9a8fc33f2fe830009011e997773071099101d69b/subxt/examples/blocks_subscribing.rs#L42 within the block subscription example.